# Release android application via azure pipeline

Tags: android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I create release pipeline on Azure DevOps and try publish android application in play google.

Now I use [Google Play extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.google-play) and when I start the process an error occurs

```
2020-09-09T03:43:27.0917248Z ##[section]Запускается: Release app.apk
2020-09-09T03:43:27.8780592Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-09T03:43:27.8781175Z Task         : Google Play - Release Bundle
2020-09-09T03:43:27.8781808Z Description  : Release an app bundle to the Google Play Store
2020-09-09T03:43:27.8782024Z Version      : 3.174.0
2020-09-09T03:43:27.8782441Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-09-09T03:43:27.8782859Z Help         : 
2020-09-09T03:43:27.8783075Z ==============================================================================
2020-09-09T03:43:35.1490887Z Found main bundle to upload: .../app.apk (version code %s)
2020-09-09T03:43:35.1776730Z (node:7588) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
2020-09-09T03:43:56.1999306Z ##[error]FetchError: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 108.177.14.95:443
2020-09-09T03:43:56.2066653Z ##[section]Завершается: Release app.apk
```

My VSTS agent is installed on the windows server behind the proxy server. On proxy server have a white list with google address `*.googleapis.com`

Agent configuration

```sh
.\config.cmd --proxyurl http://... --proxyusername ... --proxypassword ... --url https://... --auth integrated --pool ... --agent vsts-agent-win-x64-2.169.1 --runAsService --windowsLogonAccount ... --windowsLogonPassword ...
```

And YAML configuration release step from pipeline

```
steps:
- task: ms-vsclient.google-play.google-play-release-bundle.GooglePlayReleaseBundle@3
  displayName: 'Release app.apk'
  inputs:
    authType: JsonFile
    serviceAccountKey: '....json'
    applicationId: ...
    bundleFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.../app.apk'
    track: alpha
    changeLogFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.../app.apk'
```

I thing this extension not work with proxy.

How fix this error?

Comment: Could you ping through www.googleapis.com from the agent windows server? And you can have a try runing your pipeline on a cloud agent to see if it still has problem connecting to googleapis.com

Comment: I have access to this site via proxy server. Now i use on prem version TFS and I can't use cloud version or agent installed on cloud

Comment: Could you try creating a Google play service connection and using Service Endpoint authentication method instead of JsonFile authType method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem with unloading we had to create additional environment variables

```
http_proxy=...
https_proxy=...
```

My proxy replaces the certificates with its own, so initially the system does not trust the CA of my organization, it was decided to ignore the validity of the certificate.
I created one more environment variable

`NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

and made adjustments to the npm setting

`npm config set strict-ssl false`

After that it was possible to connect to a google server and publish the application.